# Python String Templates

Tags: python, string

We are using string template to replace some values in Python String by supplying a dict . It works fine .  However despite using safe_substitute this below code doesnt work as expected . Any idea why ?

```
from string import Template 
obj = Template("$$Tag$$") 
obj.safe_substitute({}) 

Output : '$Tag$' Expected : '$$Tag$$' 
(As there is no value to replace in the dict supplied .)
```

This same issue happens for '####' if I make '##' as the delimiter . Anyone knows why is it ignoring an extra delimiter ? Just trying to understand what happens under the hood .

Comment: `doesnt work as expected`: What would you have expected exactly?

Comment: Any reason for the down vote expect I didnt clarify the expected result ? Hope its a SO question .

Comment: Awesome guys ! I get the point , escaping thats the only way to put the real value if that is a delimiter ! Thats the detail I wanted to know . Its same as '\\' in Linux bash I think . Anyway thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings):

> `$$` is an escape; it is replaced with a single `$`.

If you want double `$`, then you can use something like:

```
>>> obj = Template("$$$$Tag$$$$")
>>> obj.safe_substitute({})
'$$Tag$$'
>>> obj.safe_substitute({'Tag':1})
'$$Tag$$'
>>> obj = Template("$$$Tag$$$") #First $ escapes the second $
>>> obj.safe_substitute({'Tag':1})
'$1$$'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc :

> "$$" is an escape; it is replaced with a single "$".

Answer (score 1):

You have to put two dollar signs for each one that you want in the output:

```
>>> Template('$$$$Tag$$$$').substitute()
'$$Tag$$'
```